# How to hook up Data Binding, Linq, DataGridView in the MVC way?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, datagridview

I'd like to separate the presentation logic and the controls as much as possible in a MVC fashion:

```
class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged { 

    private IEnumerable<Domain> _domains;
    public IEnumerable<Domain> Domains { 
        get { return _domains; } 
        set { _domains = value; SendPropertyChanged("Domains");
    }
}

class MyControl 
{ 
    // m_Grid's hooked up to m_BindingSource 
    private DataGridView m_Grid;
    private BindingSource m_BindingSouce;
    public void SetModel( MyModel model )
    {
        m_BindingSource.DataSource = model.Domains;
    }
}

class Controller
{
    private MyModel _model;
    private void UpdateDomains()
    {
        // predicate is built on user inputs
        _model.Domains = db.GetDomains( predicate );               
    }
}

// extra code to create Controller, MyModel, and MyControl.
```

When MyModel.Domains is changed, an event is fired to inform MyControl that its m_BindingSource.DataSource is changed.  However, the grid isn't updated with the new values.
To fix this problem, MyControl is changed to:

```
class MyControl 
{        
    public void SetModel( MyModel model )
    {
        m_BindingSource.DataSource = model.Domains;
        model.Domains.PropertyChanged += OnDataChanged;          
    }
    private void OnDataChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource.DataSource = _model.Data.Users;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why is this needed?  One of the main benefits of DataBinding is to alleviate programmers from managing PropertyChanged events.  Ironically, BindingSouce is able to detect changes on MyModel.Domains.  I experimented updating the DataSource inside a handler of m_BindingSource.DataSourceChanged.  After the change, the grid stops updating.

Comment: I think model, view, presenter is really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

See if an ObservableCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx 
or BindingList http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx makes any difference.

btw you made a typo (forgot the 'r'):

```
private BindingSource m_BindingSouce;
```

Comment: BindingList didn't help.  Will take a look at ObservableCollection